# how to generate a table of Monday dates that from a specific Monday to current date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, recursive-query

In SQL Server I need to generate a table of Mondays up to the current date.
The starting date is always `2020-04-27`, which is a Monday.
For example, if today is `2020-05-25`, I need a table like below:

```
    date
0   2020-04-27
1   2020-05-04
2   2020-05-11
3   2019-05-18
4   2019-05-25
```

If today's date is `2020-05-23`, then it's:

```
    date
0   2020-04-27
1   2020-05-04
2   2020-05-11
3   2019-05-18
```

How I can produce the table like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate the list of dates:

```
WITH mondays AS (
  SELECT CAST('2020-04-27' AS date) AS monday
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, 1, monday)
  FROM mondays
  WHERE DATEADD(WEEK, 1, monday) <= GETDATE()
)
SELECT *
FROM mondays
```

Output:

```
monday
2020-04-27
2020-05-04
2020-05-11
2020-05-18
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2742a3d0f01443fb7690fae64cb4422c)

Note that if you want to generate a list of more than 100 dates, you will need to increase the maximum recursion level (which defaults to 100). This can be done by adding `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` to the end of the query i.e.

```
SELECT *
FROM mondays
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Note:  You might need `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` if there are more than 100 Mondays in the result set.

Answer (score 2):

Use `master..spt_values`  this **default table** to attain this

```
DECLARE @DATEFROM DATE ='2020-04-27',
@DATETO DATE= '2020-05-25'

SELECT ALLDATES AS MONDATES FROM 
(SELECT DATEADD(D, NUMBER, @DATEFROM) AS ALLDATES FROM MASTER..SPT_VALUES 
WHERE TYPE = 'P' AND NUMBER BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(DD, @DATEFROM,   @DATETO)) AS D1    
WHERE DATENAME(DW, D1.ALLDATES)IN('MONDAY')
```